# MySQL PDO WHERE = $variable

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this PHP function that I want to get data from a database just by calling `get_database_data()`

In this function I have two variables that should be used in `WHERE $variable1 = $variable2`.

I know you could use `"WHERE ".$variable1." = ".$variable2`. It's works with `$variable2`, but not `$variable1`.

Something else I could use, or how do I make this work?

**EDIT:**

There is no errors, but the row I don't get any rows returned

**EDIT2:**

I've got it to work, using: `"WHERE $variable1 = ".$variable2`

Comment: may be `"WHERE $variable1 = ".$variable2` ?

Comment: @RichardBernards my bad updated.

Comment: What exactly is not working? Are there any errors?

Comment: Are you force to use variable in your fieldname?

Comment: Why not posting the whole query? No rows return means there is an error.

Comment: Are you trying to use the variable as a value, or a column-name? Because as it stands, you're doing the former.

Answer (score 0):

You should use prepared statements.

Here is a snippet that can be used to form a function that can return the data you need. You should be able to modify this quite easily to your needs.

```
   function get_database_data($variable1,$variable2)
   {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=url;dbname=somedb", "user", "pass");
        $sqlUpdate = "SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE {$variable1} = :variable2";
        $sthUpdate = $dbh->prepare($sqlUpdate);
        $sthUpdate->bindParam(':variable2', $variable2, PDO::PARAM_STR, 12);
        $sthUpdate->execute();
        $result = $sthUpdate->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }



    print_r(get_database_data('fieldname','value'));
```

I found this question quite interesting and would suggest you give it a read also:

[Can I use a PDO prepared statement to bind an identifier (a table or field name) or a syntax keyword?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23482104/can-i-use-a-pdo-prepared-statement-to-bind-an-identifier-a-table-or-field-name)